# The two types of Return keys on keyboard layouts

Tags: history, keyboards, design-choices

Why have these two types of Return keys persisted to this day? A quick look at different keyboards from different keyboard manufacturers from today shows the Shift-style Return seems to have more presence. What is the history behind these two different shaped Return keys?

```
    ┌────┐
    └─┐  │    ┌──────┐
      │  │    └──────┘
      └──┘
   
 Return #1    Shift-style Return #2
```

Comment: FWIW the VT100 had a mirror L shaped Return key: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:DEC_VT100_terminal.jpg but its predecessor the VT52 had a rectangular one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Terminal-dec-vt52.jpg

Comment: My Dell laptop looks like they had a VT100 layout in mind as a possibility. It's a conventional US layout, with chiclet keys, **but** the return and backslash keys share a single hole in the sheet metal,, which is "mirror L shaped".

Comment: I only ever see version #1 these days

Comment: Don't forget the other 2 shapes: mirror L (IBM '84 AT), and a vertical bar (often with a smaller raised area on the keycap as on the IBM '81 model F). [Some pictures (US layout)](http://xahlee.info/kbd/ibm_pc_keyboards.html).  The former is a similar shape to the return icon (which I assume to represent a carriage return on a typewriter,  though it looks like it should be LF/CR).  I'm sure I've seen the mirror L style on something more recent as well (UK QWERTY), but it's not here in work. (A Cherry at home as a spare?)

Comment: This question on SuperUser has some answers listing most of these shapes, it comes down to history and keybnoard layout. The Mirror L is especially common in Russia and Asia, for example: https://superuser.com/q/837448/658200

Comment: @OmarL - by contrast, I won't even *use* version 1, and have no problem buying version #2.  (I'm in the USA)

Comment: I hit the damn slash at least half the time, because it used to be both of those whole things. Who's fault is this? Everything went down hill after the Apple IIe....

Comment: there are actually 4 types of Enter key, not 2

Comment: I have previously made laptop buying decisions based on the keyboard having type #1 instead of type #2, and I would NEVER buy a standalone keyboard with type #2.  As you can see with another-dave's comment, there exist people with the exact opposite opinion.  I'd say that's probably why they both still exist.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

*[I assume the question is specific about prevalent PC-Keyboards. For [typewriters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typewriter) in general the history is of course way more diverse, not to mention even more [computer keyboard layouts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout). Wiki got several dozend pages about them.]*

> Why have these two types of Return keys persisted to this day?

It's the 'international' **102 key** layout (#1) vs the US **101 key** layout (#2).

(104/105 key keyboards are variations thereof with added <kbd>Menu</kbd> and <kbd>Win</kbd> key(s), not changed otherwise)

Both are defined in ISO 9995, where #2 style (US) is registered as  *ISO/IEC 9995-2* while #1 is  *ISO/IEC 9995-3*. Same for ANSI, as they adopted the ISO standard - after all, the age of national standards is a bygone one.

> Shift-style Return seems to have more presence.

This depends much on the area you live in. The 'shift style' (101 key) is prevalent in the US, Netherlands, Czech, Slovak, Turkey and in part in Poland. All (?) other countries (in Europe) use the 102 key by default (*1).

---

Examples:

[image]

**US 101 Key Keyboard Layout**
(taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY#/media/File:KB_United_States.svg))

[image]

**UK 102 Key Keyboard Layout**
(taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY#/media/File:KB_United_Kingdom.svg))

The return key was 'reformatted' to allow the addition of one more letter in the middle (<kbd>A</kbd>...) row, as many non-English keyboards placed their letters to the right side of <kbd>L</kbd>.

---

While the difference between US and UK is rather marginal, other languages do need to fit many more characters, such as the German E1 Layout:

[image]

**German Extended 102 Keyboard Layout**
(taken from [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Deutsche_Tastaturbelegung_E1_nach_E_DIN_2137-01--2020-11.png))

This is rather a to-the-max example as the [DIN 2137 E1](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/E1_(Tastaturbelegung)) layout is newer definition, intended to support most European languages.

---

Historically, typewriter keyboard layouts were way more diverse. (Most) UK keyboards already had, back in typewriter times, two additional keys over US keyboards, despite being designed for the same language. Even more differences were found in typewriters for other languages.

By now cheap PC clone keyboards represent a *de-facto* norm for these two layouts.

How strong the de-facto standards are was something DIN has had to learn within the last few years. To improve usage for more different (European) scripts DIN 2137 introduced a new layout in 2012. Only a single keyboard model was ever produced by Cherry to this standard - now already a collectable. Thus the actual E1/E2 revision went back to the 102 key layout.

Only some Asian (mainly Japanese) layouts still differ.

---

*1 - "By default" meaning as an 'official' (*de-jure*) standard for that country. Practical use may differ. Poland is a great example here, as their standards were based on the 102 (in fact on even more complex ones), but people used a modified 101 layout, simply because US keyboards were cheaply available from China. The result was the so called 'Programmers Keyboard' which by now has reached standard recognition - simply by being rather common. "Die normativen Kraft des Faktischen" as [Georg Jellinek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg_Jellinek) had put it in 1900 :))

Comment: `The 'shift style' (101 key) is prevalent in the US, Netherlands, Czech, Slovak Turkey and in part in Poland.` Also in English-speaking parts of Canada, where the US layout is used. (Source: I'm Canadian)

Comment: I contend that the German E1 layout does not _need_ many of those symbols, even to support most European languages (for example, the arrows and mathematical symbols are there for convenience, and many of the under-character combining forms are not actually used in European languages at all).

Comment: Great answer, I read the question and wondered what #2 was and why I had never seen it - a geo-based standard makes sense.

Comment: @ssokolow Oh, of course there are variations of practical usage, might it be due programmers using US (like) keyboards out of 'tradition' or because of cheap and fitting imports. The list was meant for whatever is the official standard. For example Norway/Sweden/Finland use the 102 by default, but you'll find a lot of people using 101. For Canada I though a Canadian/French 102 would be the official standard. Poland is a special case, as there is an official, but because of cheap imports US or German are more common than the standard, resulting in finally acknowledging this a few years ago :)

Comment: Aren't the layouts you have labeled as 101/102 actually 103/104, since they have Win & Menu?

Comment: @hobbs They are as 104/105 (there are two win keys by HID definition),  as mentioned right at the start. These keys have been added the same way for both versions, so not making any difference regarding the return key shape.

Comment: @Raffzahn I'd never even seen a non-US101/104 layout until my mother bought a new PC in the 2000s, and, some time since September 1997 when we bought our last PC, manufacturers had stopped just bundling US101/104 keyboards in favour of CA102/... with the non-QWERTY markings in a secondary color. I doubt anyone outside the province of Quebec sees an exclusively CA102/... keyboard unless they seek them out and, given the low price of aftermarket membrane keyboards of equivalent quality, I suspect a *lot* of anglophone users spend the extra $7 to get a US104 Enter key on their desktop PCs.

Comment: No clue how many anglophone Canadians buying new laptops actively seek out US layouts to match their desktop PCs though.

Comment: It's important to understand that Canada may be officially bilingual, but it's more that we have one province that's primarily francophone, lots of people who forgot their high school French, and, in 1982, when we patriated our constitution, the Quebec premier (provincial counterpart to a prime minister as a state governor is to a president) had enough leverage to demand measures to protect Quebec French from withering away into an interlang under the onslaught of anglophone culture in the most Americanized of the commonwealth countries. (eg. the "notwithstanding clause" in our constitution.)

Comment: I haven't done a thorough survey of stores but, if you look at, for example, Canada Computers (a brick-and-mortar chain with stores across English-speaking Canada), their catalogue lists 429 "English" keyboards, 4 "French" keyboards, and 3 "Bilingual" ones. This is a country where, even under Quebec's language laws, the law will specify advertising copy must use a properly etymologically constructed French word for smartphone and everyone on the street will just use a direct and obvious adaptation of the English.

Comment: @ssokolow Nice rant, just language politics are not really topic here. We're living in a free world - at least for small decisions like that. Shops offer what people need and people buy what shops offer.  This leads to interesting combination, like German keyboards in Czech Republik or Poland, despite featuring letters they (almost) never need and their country having different Standards for keyboards. BTW: there are also a Canadian (aka bilingual) 101 and 102 with QWERTY available. Choice is a great, isn't it?

Comment: @Raffzahn I wasn't intending it as a rant. Just a clarification of how much of a large-scale divergence there is between "what people in the other nine provinces and three territories use" and "the official standard". It's almost like expecting the U.S. to standardize on English-Spanish bilingual keyboards because of the large number of Spanish-speaking people in states like California and Texas where big tech companies tend to be based. (Yes, I know Redmond is in Washington.)

Comment: @ssokolow Being European, handling of multiple language, as well as divergence between various PoV isn't much to mention - guess what, instead of Quebec to the east, we got France to the west :))

Comment: That's fine... but if you said "and in part of Poland", it's a glaring oversight to not also say "much of Canada".

Comment: @ssokolow Erm ... you may want to read again, I wrote "in part **in** Poland". It's not about region or language, but use case - based on usage tradition. Applications coming from a typewriter/office background usually operate keyboards based on the legacy layout, while ones coming from a  modern (PC) computer background use the so called 'Programmer Keyboard'. Yes, Poland is special in that, which is why it made sense to mention it. Also note the next sentence talking about _Europe_.

Comment: Ahh. Fair enough... though I'm still on the fence about not mentioning how over 95% of the Canadian aftermarket keyboard market appears to still be US-layout boards, even if our bundled/laptop keyboards are International-layout.

Answer (score 10):

The difference is between different keyboard layout standards.

The small height Enter key is from ANSI US layout and large height Enter key is from ISO UK layout.

As the Enter keys have different shape, also other keys are found in different locations as per the respective standards.

Also note that each country may have a certain standard layout and it is not just about having those two standards. Some countries might base on US layout or on UK layout, due to historical, political or whatever reasons.

And since computer users in each country have been accustomed to a certain standard and muscle memory to where each button is, it would be quite difficult to suddenly change to a single standard. While the layout might be different, for example in countries that have more or different letters, the keycaps are also different, not just the shape of Enter key. So it would not make any sense to even try to make keyboards with only one layout. Nobody would buy a keyboard or a laptop if it has a wrong layout or keycaps for a given country.

Comment: They are both "ISO layouts", as both are defined in ISO 9995

Comment: I can't disagree with that. The US layout would still be an ANSI standard and the UK layout would not.

Comment: Since ANSI simply [adopted the standard](https://webstore.ansi.org/Standards/ISO/ISOIEC99952010), it defines as well both versions :))

Comment: Neat actually. Well, given the circumstances, would it suffice to say that they originally were defined in different standards, and that's why they are *commonly* called as ANSI or ISO layouts even today?

Comment: Old habits die hard. After all, we still use 'Horse Powers' to define our cars engines or Watt numbers of classic light bulbs to mark the brightness of LED replacements.

Comment: @Raffzahn That would be "(Tungsten incandescent-equivalent) Watts" - as Watts is a unit of power, not luminous flux ("brightness"). Which is almost as bad as Americans who use "Pounds of Force" when pounds are a unit of mass, not force.... brb need to scream

Comment: @Dai - well, pound is used as both a unit of mass and a unit of force, but in different systems. In the pound (force) system, the unit of mass is the slug. And you thought it couldn't get more confusing...

Comment: @Dai Jup, non engineering savvy people are just barbarians. They use whatever they heard once and associated via some ugly shortcut. Works fine at first, so it must work always ... slow, I'm joining :)

Comment: @JonCuster it can... just remember calories vs Calories (the latter actually being kilocalories)...

Comment: @Ruslan - oh yes... Kids these days don't get the range of systems that I did back when. Even Jackson has gone SI for most of it rather than Gaussian units. Sigh. At least chemical engineers still get a whole mess thrown at them.

Comment: @JonCuster don't forget those weirdos who use pound as a unit of money.

Answer (score 9):

There are other shapes too.  I always liked this fat rectangular one on some of the IBM Selectric typewriters and I really believe I remember this shape on some early (~1980s) keyboards as well.  Or maybe I'm just remembering some IBM terminals that had this sort of thing.  Or maybe I'm just wishing for it ...

[image]

Comment: looks like that keyboard could still fit the UK-style return key, there's the little gap there between "return" and the key to the right of "P". Given how there's other keys here that are oddly shaped, I kinda wonder they just didn't mold the "return" with that little protrusion too. That gap is actually really ugly.

Comment: Odd that they made the return key so large, yet deliberately made the top of the shift keys smaller than the base of the key.

Comment: Some of other interesting shapes are the [PMD85](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Tesla_PMD_85-2A.jpg) - two identical Enter keys side-by-side (marked `EOL`) and [PP01](https://pp01.borik.net/images/pp01.jpg) - two keys marked `CR` and `LF` (and a rather unusual keyboard layout).

Comment: @DrSheldon It's a usability issue. At the time if the Selectric (new) users were coming from classic typewriters that simply didn't have wide shift keys - something that would have been quite wobbly on mechanical typewriters, where shift keys were really operated with force to lift the basket. Electronics allowed it to add a pleasing wider shape, but to make the type feel right, it needed to be narrowed again. It was only until a later, computer savvy generation came, no longer trained with real typewriters that appreciated the wider keycaps.